# mostrar loader mientras se carga codigo php

Tags: php, ajax

Nesecito mostrar un loader,div o imagen mientras se carga el codigo php

pagina home.php

```
<form method="get" target="_blank" action="pagina2.php">
<input type="text" name="inputuno"></input>
 <input type="text" name="inputdos"></input>
 <input type="submit" value="envia"></input>
</form>
```

pagina pagina2.php

```
$variableuno=$_GET['inputuno'];
$variabledos=$_GET['inputdos'];
//loop mysqli;
<html> resultados consulta </html>
```

Comment: Probe con jquery y no me funciona , primero se ejecuta el codigo php y despues muestra el loader.

Comment: el codigo php no carga ... se ejecuta ...

Comment: eso pasa por que estan haciendo las cosas a lo mejor en un orden incorreto; normalmente utilizamos single page aplication (SPA) para las pagias web, pero contanos mas, esto ocurre al cargar por primera vez tu pagina o cuando entra a cierto anchor???

Comment: lo haces con ajax o que ???

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un contenedor donde va a estar tu imagen.

```
<body class="login">
    <div class="loading"></div> 
    ...
</div>
```

luego a la clase del contenedor le agregas la imagen y propiedades necesarias:

```
> .loading  {
>     position: fixed;
>     left: 0px;
>     top: 0px;
>     width: 100%;
>     height: 100%;
>     z-index: 9999;
>     background: url('Images/loading_2.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);
>     opacity: .8; }
```

después con jquery, ocultas la imagen, cuando toda la pagina cargue.

```
  $(window).load(function () {
             $(".loading").fadeOut("slow");
   });
```

tener presente, que la imagen es la primera que se muestra, y lo que hacemos es ocultarla con jquery cuando la pagina termina de cargar.

Comment: Gracias Sergio  por tu respuesta pero no me funciona ya probé , y el php se ejecuta antes y después muestra el loader osea tarda 30 segundos en cargar que es lo que demora las consultas sql

Comment: me parece que a la pregunta le faltan detalles para dar una respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar ajax para hacer la petición al servidor web y al iniciar la petición mostrar el loading y al terminar la petición ocultar el loading.

```
<script>
    var divCargando = document.getElementById('cargandoDiv');

    $( document ).ajaxSend(function() {
      divCargando.show();
    });

    $( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {  
      divCargando.hide();
    });
</script>
```

con ese código logras que cada peticion ajax que hagas se muestre el loading y se oculte cuando se termine.

Luego, necesitas hacer el submit a traves de $.post() o $.get() y no a traves del submit del formulario.

esto es un ejemplo generico

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.get("pagina2.php", function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
});
```

Comment: Tenes algun ejemplo Rodolfo?

Comment: actualice la respuesta con alguna guía de lo que puedes hacer

Comment: me parece que a la pregunta le faltan detalles para dar una respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({type: 'POST', url: "url",
        data: {key:value},
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            // hacer lo que sea antes de que termine request
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            //al finalizar el request
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //en caso de error
        }
    });
```

**[puedes consultar la documentacion de beforeSend y ajax de jquery aqui](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)**

Comment: Gracias javier , ahora veo la documentacion y cualquier cosa vuelvo a comentar!!

Comment: a mi me va de maravilla, solo que es codigo un poco viejo, JQuery va de salida.

Comment: me parece que a la pregunta le faltan detalles para dar una respuesta.